# SqlException: Invalid column name 'CountryMasterCountryId'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am doing CRUD operation using asp .net core 6 MVC (visual studio 2022). For this i complete County Create,Update,Delete,Read operation. but now i am trying cascading dropdown in state with relation county db. when i write "public virtual CountryMaster CountryMaster" and "public virtual ICollection StateMasters" in the models on state and country it give me error of sqlException:Invalid column name 'CountryMasterCountryId'. here is CountryMaster model
'''

```
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter Country")]
    public string CountryName { get; set; } = null!;

    [Display(Name ="When Entered")]
    public DateTime WhenEntered { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    [Display(Name ="When Modified")]
    public DateTime WhenModified { get; set; }= DateTime.UtcNow;

    public virtual ICollection<StateMaster> StateMasters { get; set; }
} '''
```

here is StateMasters model
'''

```
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please Enter State Name")]
    public string StateName { get; set; } = null!;

    
    [Display(Name = "Country Name")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "When Entered")]
    public DateTime WhenEntered { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    [Display(Name = "When Modified")]
    public DateTime WhenModified { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    public virtual CountryMaster CountryMaster { get; set; } 
}
```

'''
What i do? Is Icollection different in .net core 6 MVC?

Comment: How you fetch data from db? Can you please share that code

Comment: Could you share the full code of the model class? Your state and country, CountryMaster and StateMaster make me confused.

Comment: In Program.cs i add code : builder.Services.AddDbContext<CustomerCrud_DemoContext>(
    option =>option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Local"))
    );

Comment: " when i write "public virtual CountryMaster CountryMaster" and "public virtual ICollection StateMasters" "When did you do this? Did it before completing CountryMaster Create,Update,Delete,Read operation ?

Answer (score 0):

The properties you added to the Model does not exist in the database.
Try to  update your database:

From the Tools menu, select NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console .

In the Package Manager Console (PMC), enter the following commands:

1: Change the the migration name

```
Add-Migration xxxx
```

2:Updates the database to the latest migration, which the previous command created

```
Update-Database
```